# No route to host docker from raspberry pi

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi

I cant connect my raspberry pi to docker hub

```
sudo docker pull portainer/portainer-ce:latest
Trying to pull repository docker.io/portainer/portainer-ce ...
Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to registry-1.docker.io:443; No route to host
```

Comment: No route to host means there's a routing problem. Maybe it's related to a proxy you must traverse to reach internet? The timeout seems more a firewall issue.

Comment: should i need open firewall to which IP. I quite not sure. i curl google.com no issue

Comment: https, port 443 for the host `registry-1.docker.io`. Can you check the connectivity with `nc -vz registry-1.docker.io 443`?

Comment: ping ot telnet to another site to validate if it is a network problem not related to docker

Comment: I tried ping facebook.com i hitting host unreachable same goest with docer io. But in my laptop no issue.  i using pi

Comment: So it is a network configuration issue in your rpi. You should start by checking whether a default gateway is defined with the command `ip route`.

Comment: i do ip route i get "172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown"

Comment: I curl facebook no issue. i curl curl: (7) Failed connect to registry-1.docker.io:443; No route to host

Comment: i stopped firewalld also still same

Comment: Can you please edit your question to provide some more details of the environment the raspberry pi is running at? Is it at your home or in an office? Is a proxy in between?